# UIScrollView canCancelContentTouches not disabling scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have subclassed UIScrollView. I am using zooming feature of scrollview.What I want is After zooming I don't want the view to be scrolled.So I do the following.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
    [self setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
}
```

But still it scrolls.

Comment: have you tried using this code "scrollView.scrollEnabled = FALSE;" into this method?

Answer (score 2):

The `canCancelContentTouches` method does not disable scrolling, as you are expecting. Instead the way it works is whenever you hold your finger down on a button or other control that is a subview of the scrollview and then start making a scrolling gesture, it will cancel the touch on the control and begin scrolling instead.

What you are looking for is:

```
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

set CanCancelContentTouches to YES